# How can i skip unique field in Yii2?

Tags: ajax, activerecord, yii2, pjax

I have a unique field that I check when editing or adding a new training course. But, for some reason, when I enter a value in a field, it does not show me a hint that the field is already taken.

In addition, I need to do this: when I change the values and did not change this unique field, but left it as it is, then the validor should not swear that the field is already taken.

Thank.

**InfCourses Model:**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['name', 'short_description', 'price', 'favorite', 'active', 'course_order', 'link'], 'required'],
        [['price', 'active'], 'integer'],
        [['favorite'], 'string'],
        [['name', 'short_description', 'link'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['active'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => InfStatuses::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['active' => 'id']],
        [['course_order'], 'integer', 'min' => 1],
        [
            ['course_order'], 'unique', 
            'targetAttribute' => ['course_order'], 
            'filter' => ['!=', 'id', Yii::$app->request->get('id')],
        ],
    ];
}
```

**Validator in InfCoursesController:**

```
public function actionValidate()
{
    $model = new InfCourses();

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
}
```

**Part of form code:**

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'validationUrl' => 'validate',
    'options' => [
        'data-pjax' => true,
    ]
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I cut code below to each action: create/update.

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
```

Then remove `validationUrl` from form component. Inside model i make this rule `[['course_order'],'unique']`... Working fine...

Answer (score 1):

Your validation is simply incorrect. You're using `Yii::$app->request->get('id')` in your rules, which is probably main source of your problems. Model should not access request or web user component directly - it breaks MVC pattern. Also putting values directly in rules in this way may give you unexpected results. You should check what query is generated by this validator, because it is hard to guess what is happening with such twisted rule.

But it may be easier to fix `actionValidate()` and distinguish between validating of new record and validating existing record:

```
public function actionValidate($id = null) {
    if (empty($id)) {
        $model = new InfCourses();
    } else {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
    }

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
}
```

Then you can limit your unique rule to:

```
[['course_order'], 'unique'],
```

Validator will be smart enough to detect that it is validating existing record and will not report unchanged fields values as duplicates. You just need to provide record ID in this action URL.

Comment: But i have problem. When i update my course without edit `course_order` field Yii show me that i already have filed with value ... but i do not change it

Look, i use validation there:

`<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        'validationUrl' => 'validate',
        'options' => [
            'data-pjax' => true,
        ]
    ]); ?>`

Comment: I have this new rule and it works, but if i add new course i do not see message for this field: `[
                ['course_order'], 
                'unique',
                'when' => function ($model, $attribute) {
                    return $model->{$attribute} !== $model->getOldAttribute($attribute);
                },
                'on' => 'update'
            ]`